# Kiel oni tradukus aŭ Esperantigus la vorton „Aggadah“

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi unue pensis, ke „Agado“ ĝustus, sed klare tio estus problema. „Agadaho“ ankaŭ ne estas ideala, ĉar hebreaj kaj judismecaj vortoj ĝenerale ne konservas la finan H-on ekde Zamenhof (ekz. Noa de Noah, Zeĥarja de Zekharyah); ĝi ne elparoliĝis en la devenlingvo kaj estas nur ortografia. Vikipedia tradukas la vorton „Haggadah“ kiel „Hagado“, tamen mi ne povus usi tion. „Aggadah“ venas de la aramea de la hebrea „Haggadah“, sed ne estas la sama afero. „Aggadah“ estas rabena literaturaĵo de paraboloj kaj rakontoj, sed „Haggadah“ estas skribaĵo, kiun oni deklamas je Seder en Pesaĥo.

Ĉu estas propra solvo por ĉi tiu situacio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oni povus forigi la finan H-on kaj konservi la antaŭfinan A-on. Tio donas "**Agadao**".